# Make a arrow disappear on ground bedrock edition

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to make a game where a team shoots a arrow and if it misses it despawns and respawns in the middle. How can I make the arrow disappear?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please, rephrase your post because it's hard to understand as it's written

Answer (score 2):

You can always put a command in a command block:

```
/execute @e[type=arrow] ~~~ detect ~~~ <block> <data, likely 0> kill @e[type=arrow]
```

Set the configuration of the command block to:

```
Repeat
Always Active
```

This may help you, but, if you shoot multiple arrows, they're all getting killed so I would recommend aiming good/don't spam or try this:

```
/kill @e[type=arrow]
```

But, you're doing the ticks on how long the arrow is able to fly. Keep in mind that 20 Ticks equals roughly 1 second. Finally, to prevent message spam on the screen, disable command block output:

```
/gamerule commandblockoutput false
```

Comment: do the commandblock on "repeating" and "always active" and if you wont get spammed also do /gamerule commandblockoutput false

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade! I've proposed an edit that adds your comment to your answer. Once approved, you can remove your comment. Great first answer! +1

Comment: instead of for the second part having `kill @e[type=arrow]`, just use `kill @s` and you wont have that issue